# Why there is an error with linked list, when i try to enter some value in int d?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm new in coding and I was wondering why this code crashes when I enter some value. There are some tutorials for this, but I don't get it.

Can someone explain `linked lists` very simple, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}tnode;

int main()
{
    tnode *head=NULL;
    tnode *new=(tnode*)malloc(sizeof(tnode));
    int d;
    scanf("%d", d);
    new->data=d;
    new->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=new;
        return;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", d);` -> `scanf("%d", &d);`

Comment: yeah...Thanx...

Comment: Note that this time, the problem is nothing to do with linked lists — it is a basic typo in the use of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a few problems in there, I think.

1. This is not an error technically, but using `new` as an identifier (for a variable or method name) is not recommended. If one were to try to use this in a c++ program it would break.
2. `scanf("%d",d)` should be `scanf("%d",&d)`; it’s expecting the address of the variable where to store the input value.
3. It doesn’t make much sense to return in the `if` statement, but if you do, you should specify a return code (your last return line has 0 as the code; you could use that, or pick a different number if you want).